# How can I trace what a javapackager-based app does when it is started on macOS?

Tags: java, debugging, javapackager

I'm written a Java-based application for macOS created using Oracle's `javapackager` from Java 8.  It worked perfectly for months until something changed, possibly due to a recent Java update, and now when I rebuild the application, the result exits without any messages when executed. Running the jar file itself directly in a terminal shell (i.e., with `java -jar path/to/my.jar`) works normally without errors.  I am at a loss to figure out what is going wrong with the `.app` version, and cannot figure out how to get any diagnostics from whatever the thing created by javapackager does.

**How can I trace what a `.app` created using `javapackager` does when it runs?**

I'm using the `-deploy -native image` option to `javapackager` from Oracles Java 1.8 u152 to create the application on OSX 10.12.6. My question is specifically about how to get the resulting `.app` to print what it is doing, or get error diagnostics, or *something*, to help figure out what it is doing under the hood.  I don't need help with running `javapackager` itself.

I thought that using `Console` would help to understand what is happening, but the information is too sparse and difficult for me to interpret. After hiding a lot of other process output, it boils down to the following being printed:

```
default 22:43:22.523842 -0800   taskgated   MacOS error: -67062
default 22:43:22.733680 -0800   SBML Test Runner    WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.6 instead of 10.12.6. This is not a bug in Gestalt -- it is a documented limitation. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
default 22:43:22.733853 -0800   SBML Test Runner    0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff97a4d1b1 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 121
default 22:43:22.733876 -0800   SBML Test Runner    1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffac28b8fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
default 22:43:22.733897 -0800   SBML Test Runner    2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffac28b8b9 dispatch_once_f + 38
default 22:43:22.733930 -0800   SBML Test Runner    3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff979db292 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 976
default 22:43:22.733982 -0800   SBML Test Runner    4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff979daaad Gestalt + 139
default 22:43:22.734010 -0800   SBML Test Runner    5   libswt-pi-cocoa-4628.jnilib         0x00000001283072de Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_Gestalt + 158
default 22:43:22.734028 -0800   SBML Test Runner    6   ???                                 0x00000001067919f4 0x0 + 4403567092
```

Although the `taskgated` error at first seemed relevant, some Googling around suggests it's a common issue and not fatal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd verify that the actual JVM starts by invoking the binary in the packaged app bundle via Terminal:

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

In case of JVM errors you'll get output printed to stdout. If you can confirm that the JVM starts normally, you might be able to do further analysis using [jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html).